# android spinner getselected item

Tags: java, android

In my `Spinner` I have a `String` `Array` for it {sedentary, lightly active, moderately active and heavily active} (this is the calculation of one's BMR)

What I want to do is get the **selected item** in a `Spinner`.

For example, when I click on **sedentary**, for **sedentary** has a value of **1.2**, the result of the **bmr** is `multiplied` by **1.2**. But I can't seem to get it work for me.

Please do check my code below:

```
private void calculateMen(){    
    String f1 = etft.getText().toString();
    String f2 = etin.getText().toString();
    String f3 = etweight.getText().toString();
    String f4 = etage.getText().toString();

    if ( (f1.isEmpty() || f2.isEmpty() || f3.isEmpty() || f4.isEmpty() ) ) 
    {   // call for custom toast
        viewErrorToast();
    } 
    else
    {
        // Metric Formula for BMR (Men) English Unit
        // 66 + ( 6.2377 x weight in kilos ) + 
        //( 12.7084 x height in cm ) - ( 6.7550 x age in years )
        String age, in, ft, weight;
        Double answer;
        age =  etage.getText().toString();
        in =  etin.getText().toString();    
        ft = etft.getText().toString();
        weight = etweight.getText().toString();

        if (spinnerText.equals("Sedentary"))
        {     
            answer =  ( ( 66 + ( 6.2377 * Double.parseDouble( weight ) ) + ( 12.7084 * ( Double.parseDouble( in ) * 12 + Double.parseDouble( ft ) ) ) - ( 6.8 * Double.parseDouble( age ) ) ) * 1.2 ); 
            //*  Double.parseDouble(actAnswer) ;    
            BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(answer);
            bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);         
            etanswer.setText(bd.toString()); 
        }
        else if (spinnerText.equals("Lightly Active"))
        {
            answer =  ( ( 66 + ( 6.2377 * Double.parseDouble( weight ) ) + ( 12.7084 * ( Double.parseDouble( in ) * 12 + Double.parseDouble( ft ) ) ) - ( 6.8 * Double.parseDouble( age ) ) ) * 1.375 ); 
            //*  Double.parseDouble(actAnswer) ;    
            BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(answer);
            bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
            etanswer.setText(bd.toString()); 
        }
        else if (spinnerText.equals("Moderately Active"))
        {
          answer =  ( ( 66 + ( 6.2377 * Double.parseDouble( weight ) ) + ( 12.7084 * ( Double.parseDouble( in ) * 12 + Double.parseDouble( ft ) ) ) - ( 6.8 * Double.parseDouble( age ) ) ) * 1.55 ); 
          //*  Double.parseDouble(actAnswer) ;    
          BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(answer);
          bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
          etanswer.setText(bd.toString()); 
        }
        else if (spinnerText.equals("Heavily Active"))
        {
          answer =  ( ( 66 + ( 6.2377 * Double.parseDouble( weight ) ) + ( 12.7084 * ( Double.parseDouble( in ) * 12 + Double.parseDouble( ft ) ) ) - ( 6.8 * Double.parseDouble( age ) ) ) * 1.725 ); 
          //*  Double.parseDouble(actAnswer) ;    
          BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(answer);
          bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
          etanswer.setText(bd.toString()); 
        }
        // call for custom toast
        viewBMRSavedToast();
    }

} // end of calculateMen method
```

Comment: to check your code you should post your logcat out put

Comment: i don't see any spinner in your code. post some relevant code, or the whole activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try modifying the code as below :

Create a field :

```
private HashMap<String, Double> spinnerValues;
```

From onCreate of your activity, call the below function :

```
private void createSpinnerValues(){
    spinnerValues=new HashMap<String, Double>();
    spinnerValues.put("Sedentary", 1.2);
    spinnerValues.put("Lightly Active", 1.375);
    spinnerValues.put("Moderately Active", 1.55);
    spinnerValues.put("Heavily Active", 1.725);
}
```

Then find your modified function to calculate as below :

```
private void calculateMen(){

    //Your Code Goes here...

     String age, in, ft, weight;
     Double answer;
     age =  etage.getText().toString();
     in =  etin.getText().toString();    
     ft = etft.getText().toString();
     weight = etweight.getText().toString();

     answer=getAnswer(age,in,ft,weight,getSelectedItemValueFromSpinnerText(spinnerText));

     BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(answer);
     bd = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);

     etanswer.setText(bd.toString()); 

     // call for custom toast
     viewBMRSavedToast();
    }

private Double getAnswer(String age, String in, String ft, String weight,
        Double selectedItemValueFromSpinner) {
    double answer = ( ( 66 + ( 6.2377 * Double.parseDouble( weight ) ) + 
             ( 12.7084 * ( Double.parseDouble( in ) * 12 + Double.parseDouble( ft ) ) )
             - ( 6.8 * Double.parseDouble( age ) ) ) * selectedItemValueFromSpinner ); 
    return answer;
}

private Double getSelectedItemValueFromSpinnerText(String spinnerText) {
    return spinnerValues.get(spinnerText);
}
```

Don't forget to include your existing code at : //Your Code Goes here...

Comment: Is it compilation or runtime error...I've not tried running that code. If its compilation error, hope you can fix it. if its runtime error, please share the logcat output so that I can help you

Comment: 08-27 14:52:33.456: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at com.fps.iHealthFirst.BMRCalculator.getAnswer(BMRCalculator.java:76)

Comment: what is the exception? can you copy paste more info from logcat...i mean the full stack trace in red color